# Receiving error 'Must have a return type' in line 54 'PopMessageBox()'

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using CustFile_DLL;

namespace FileConvertorPA03
{
    class Program
    {
        //add these to handle I/O
        //instatiate streamreader
        private static StreamReader TextfileIn = new StreamReader("customers.txt");
        //instantiate the dll
        private static CustFileClass CustObj = new CustFileClass();
        //a few vars
        private static string gs_InPutBuffer = "";
        private static Int32 gi_TotalRec = 0, gi_FirstRecNo = 0;
        private static bool gb_FirstRec = true;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while ((gs_InPutBuffer = TextfileIn.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                ParsetoAttributes();
                CustObj.AddObject();
            }//end while
            PopMessageBox();
            TextfileIn.Close();
        }//end main

        //method to parse input buffer to class attributes
        private static void ParsetoAttributes()
        {
            CustObj.s_CustName = gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(000, 033).Trim();
            CustObj.s_CustAddress = gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(033, 032).Trim();
            CustObj.s_CustZip = gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(065, 005);
            CustObj.s_CustPhone = gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(070, 010);
            CustObj.d_CustDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(000, 004));
        }//end parse attributes

        //method to count records added
        static void CountRecs()
        {
            if (gb_FirstRec == true)
            {
                gi_FirstRecNo = CustObj.i_CustNumber;
                gb_FirstRec = false;
            }//end if 
            gi_TotalRec++;
        }//end count recs

        public static PopMessageBox()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Message: \n\tRecords Added \t{0,6}n\tFirst    Rec    Added\t     {1,6}\n\tLast   Rec  Added\t{2,6}"),
            gi_TotalRec, gi_FirstRecNo, CustObj.i_CustNumber, "File Conversion Message:",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }//end class
    }
}//end namespace enter code here
```

I'm receiving the error

> 'Method must have a return type'

I am unsure of the problem and have been unsuccessful in finding an answer on Google.  I'm very new to C#, any help would be greatly appreciated!

This occurs on line 54 'public static PopMessageBox()'

Answer (score 3):

Change your

```
public static PopMessageBox()
```

to

```
public static void PopMessageBox()
```

Since your `PopMessageBox` method doesn't return anything, you should use [`void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as a return type.

> When used as the return type for a method, **void specifies that the
>   method does not return a value.**

Comment: +1 beat me for 3 seconds :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky fastest rabbit win the race `:)`

Comment: @SonerGönül, After entering in void, I received 7 errors, regarding arguments 'cannot convert int to string'.  'Cannot convert int to System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon'

Comment: @user3025941 You had one error before you add `void` and you have 7 error after you add `void`? My brain just overflowed.. Anyway on which line you get cannot `convert int to string` error?

Comment: @SonerGönül The problem is referring to the code just below the addition of void, I believe the problem is in the format but I haven't been able to locate it. (Lines 56-58)

Comment: @SonerGönül Error- 'Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string, string, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions, bool)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Rew\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FileConvertorPA03\FileConvertorPA03\Program.cs 56 13 FileConvertorPA03'

Comment: Closing parenthesys for the String.Format doesn't include the arguments. Move it after the last argument. `CustObj.i_CustNumber`

Comment: @Steve Thanks! Your advice got rid of those errors, now I just have a few formatting errors including semicolons and periods(according to Visual Studio) Here is the code that contains the errors '            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Message: \n\tRecords Added \t{0,6}n\tFirst    Rec    Added\t     {1,6}\n\tLast   Rec  Added\t{2,6}"),
            gi_TotalRec, gi_FirstRecNo, CustObj.i_CustNumber, "File Conversion Message:");
            MessageBoxButtons.OK MessageBoxIcon.Information;'

Answer (score 1):

Add `void` return type to your method:

```
public static void PopMessageBox()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Wrong use of `String.Format`

```
public static void PopMessageBox()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Message: \n\tRecords Added \t{0}n\tFirst    Rec    Added\t     {1}\n\tLast   Rec  Added\t{2}", gi_TotalRec, gi_FirstRecNo, CustObj.i_CustNumber), "File Conversion Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Comment: I was able to get rid of the errors with your advice, however when I run the program without debugging it crashes and says the "FormatException was unhandled" in the line 'CustObj.d_CustDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(000, 004));'

Comment: Check your gs_InPutBuffer. If you problem solve then try to accept this as an answer.

Comment: I've been unable to find the correct format in my coding book or on the internet, would you care to steer me in the right direction? thanks for your help!